# Csh script wait for multiple pid

Tags: linux, csh

Does the wait command work in a csh script to wait for more than 1 PID to finish?

Where the `wait` command waits for all the PID listed to complete before moving on to the next line

e.g.

```
wait $job1_pid $job2_pid $job3_pid
nextline
```

as the documentation online that I usually see only shows the wait command with only 1 PID, although I have read of using wait for multiple PID, like here :
http://www2.phys.canterbury.ac.nz/dept/docs/manuals/unix/DEC_4.0e_Docs/HTML/MAN/MAN1/0522____.HTM

which says quote "If **one or more pid operands are specified** that represent known process IDs,the wait utility waits until all of them have terminated"

Comment: A well worn advice:  change to another shell for scripting.  (My "qualification" to give it: I use `tcsh` as my interactive shell, and have used it here or there for scripting as well)

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Comment: Is... that a Digital Unix manpage? Man, that takes me back. How in the world did you dig up that fossil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the builtin `wait` command in `csh` can only wait for all jobs to finish. The command in the documentation that you're referencing is a separate executable that is probably located at `/usr/bin/wait` or similar. This executable cannot be used for what you want to use it for.

I recommend using `bash` and its more powerful `wait` builtin, which does allow you to wait for specific jobs or process ids.

---

From the `tcsh` man page, `wait` waits for all background jobs. `tcsh` is compatible with `csh`, which is what the university's documentation you linked is referring to.

> **wait**     The shell waits for all background jobs.  If the shell is interactive, an interrupt will disrupt the wait and cause the shell
>   to  print the names and job numbers of all outstanding jobs.

You can find this exact text on the [csh documentation here](http://www2.phys.canterbury.ac.nz/dept/docs/manuals/unix/DEC_4.0e_Docs/HTML/MAN/MAN1/0144____.HTM).

The `wait` executable described in the documentation is actually a separate command that waits for a list of process ids.

However, the `wait` executable *is not actually capable of waiting for the child processes of the running shell script* and has no chance of doing the right thing in a shell script.

For instance, on OS X, `/usr/bin/wait` is this shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
# $FreeBSD: src/usr.bin/alias/generic.sh,v 1.2 2005/10/24 22:32:19 cperciva Exp $
# This file is in the public domain.
builtin `echo ${0##*/} | tr \[:upper:] \[:lower:]` ${1+"$@"}
```

Anyway, I can't get the `/usr/bin/wait` executable to work reliably in a Csh script ... because the the background jobs are not child processes of the `/usr/bin/wait` process itself.

```
#!/bin/csh -f

setenv PIDDIR "`mktemp -d`"

sleep 4 &

ps ax | grep 'slee[p]' | awk '{ print $1 }' > $PIDDIR/job

/usr/bin/wait `cat $PIDDIR/job`
```

I would highly recommend writing this script in bash or similar where the builtin wait does allow you to wait for pids and capturing pids from background jobs is easier.

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 4 &
pid_sleep_4="$!"

sleep 7 &
pid_sleep_7="$!"

wait "$pid_sleep_4"
echo "waited for sleep 4"

wait "$pid_sleep_7"
echo "waited for sleep 7"
```

If you don't want to rewrite the entire `csh` script you're working on, you can call out to bash from inside a `csh` script like so.

```
#!/bin/csh -f

bash <<'EOF'

sleep 4 &
pid_sleep_4="$!"

sleep 7 &
pid_sleep_7="$!"

wait "$pid_sleep_4"
echo "waited for sleep 4"

wait "$pid_sleep_7"
echo "waited for sleep 7"

'EOF'
```

Note that you must end that heredoc with `'EOF'` including the single quotes.

Comment: `wait` can't work as an external command. A process can only wait for its own children, and background processes are children of the shell, not of a new process spawned by the shell.

Comment: Re "*A process can only wait for its own children*", fyi, non-parent's can wait for process to end in Windows

Comment: What if I am waiting for multiple time undeterministic processes. Like:

`./random_time_process1 &`
`job1 = $!`
`./random_time_process2 &`
`job2 = $!`

`wait $job1`
`wait $job2`

how would wait react if job2 terminates faster than job1 ?

Comment: @TheSprintingEngineer in bash, the `wait` builtin will wait for the specified process regardless of which other processes finish first. If you need to react to the order in which jobs finish, then I'd recommend using Perl or Python. The other alternative if you want to react to the job order is to have your jobs create temporary files in a directory when they start and remove them when they're done and then have a loop in your bash script that checks the contents of the directory once a second. Doing weird things in a shell script will make it less reliable and harder to maintain.